# find words that start with specific letter

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read file.txt with some content like this:

jone
sia
alex
jad

and using node js I want to find the words that start with letter j
this is what I write:

```
let fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./file.txt', (err, info)=>{
    let j;
    let con = 0;
    console.log(err)
    if(err) return;
    for (j=0; j < info.length; ++j)
    if (info[j] == 10)
    con++;
    console.log(con)
    if(info.indexOf('j') > -1){
        console.log(info.toString())
       }
})
```

I want to print the number of lines in text file and the words that start with letter j
but the counter result is 3 while it should be 4 and it prints all info:

```
jone
sia
alex
jad
```

while it should print **jone** and **jad** only

how solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your file.txt:

```
jone
sia
alex
jad
```

And here is the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const output = fs
  .readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8')
  .trim()
  .split('\n')
  .filter(word => word.includes('j'));

console.log(output);
```

This will get you everything that includes 'j'

If you want something that will start with j you can write your own filter function like so:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const output = fs
  .readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8')
  .trim()
  .split('\n');

function filter(names, index, letter) {
  return names.filter(word => word.charAt(index) === letter);
}

console.log('Length of originanl list: ', output.length);
console.log('Filtered List: ',  filter(output, 0, 'j'));
console.log('Length of filtered list: ',  filter(output, 0, 'j').length);
```

[Live Demo Here](https://repl.it/@sarkism/StrictKnowledgeableKeyboard)

Comment: I mean number of lines in file which should be 4 here

Comment: So the number of lines in the original file, not the filtered results? You can simply call `.length` on the output...

Comment: thanks I accept your answer but if you can please help me with how to get the number of lines which not start with letter j which should be 2 here

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`readline`**](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) build in core module and do something like this:

```
var rl = require('readline'), fs = require('fs')

var lineReader = rl.createInterface({ input: fs.createReadStream('file.txt') })

lineReader.on('line', function (name) {
  if(name.startsWith('j'))
    console.log(name)
})
```

See it [working here](https://repl.it/@akrion/readFileLineByLine?language=nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the regular expressions approach.

`info` should be of type `string`, therefore it is possible for you to use the `String.prototype` function `match()`, like so:

`let matches = info.match(expression);`

or in your case: `let matches = info.match(/\bj\w+/g);` ([example](https://regexr.com/43258))

you can use regex to detect how many lines the text files has by detecting how many `line breaks` you have in your raw data (if possible):

`let lines = info.match(/\n/g).length + 1;` ([example](https://regexr.com/4325h))

Answer (score 1):

All these answers are incredibly over-complicated.

Simply iterate through all words and check if it start with the letter:

```
for (const word of wordList.split("\n")) {
    if (word.startsWith("j")) console.log(`${word} start with the letter j`);
}
```